# Sudden and sharp chest pains

Tags: heart-disease, ribs-ribcage

Since three or four years ago, I started feeling sudden chest pains around once or twice a month. These pains can be relieved when I stretch my ribs left and right that can remove the pain. Am I facing a heart related disease, or are the pains something to do with the ribs? I am a non smoker with no family history of heart diseases.

Comment: You have to be more precise. Do you have any other symptoms, did you pull/stretch a muscle maybe, do you take any medications (side effects), your stress/anxiety levels, your age etc.. It could be loads of things but it can also be nothing serious...

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Personal medical advice is strictly off-topic here, so I'm voting to close. For more information please have a look at the [help]. A suspicion of a heart disease is a serious one, so a visit to the doctor's is definitely in order.

Comment: As Lucky says, this is an off topic subject. I would, however, encourage you to visit your personal medical provider. Chest pains, whether they seem innocuous or not are not something to be dismissed or taken lightly.